# Search in gridview while I type anything in textbox

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to search in gridview with a textbox while I will type in textbox eg. when I write 'uok' then in gridvew it searches for 'uok'.  Search without any button or enter etc. please give me full code in C# asp.net or tell me JavaScript function if it is needed

I have tried this but for this search I have to press enter or click for firing event

```
protected void Search_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   

    con = new SqlConnection(connect);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.CommandText = "Seelct_master_search_record_text";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@text", Search.Text);
    dt.Clear();

    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
    da.SelectCommand = cmd;
    da.Fill(dt);
    con.Open();


    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();


}
```

I want [this](http://my.iraciti.com/master_search.html) type of search.

Comment: get data from database whatever u type in textbox and use text changed event

Comment: not one can provide you code according to your requirement i m just giving you idea how you can do that

Comment: in text_changed event we have to hit enter or click anywhere to get the event fire. But i want that what ever i type it searches instantly in gridview. for eg you can check in following link http://my.iraciti.com/master_search.html .

Comment: Before you ask for code, can you please provide your own attempts at resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

make autopostback property true for textbox